# Start minikube with 2 worker nodes - arm64 and amd64

Tags: kubernetes, arm, x86-64, minikube

I would like to start the Minikube Kubernetes cluster with 2 worker nodes - for amd and arm images. It is possible to start the Minikube with a multi-node setup (e.g. minikube start --nodes 2), but node architecture depends on the host. Is there any way to start Minikube cluster with 2 worker nodes for amd and arm images?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as base minikube architecture is either arm/amd

refer: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9762

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-arm

curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-arm64
```